# how to get link from textview to open an activity

Tags: android

i have 3 activities in my project. The last activity shows content in textview from database, this content have links. i want to open a new activity to display results of these links on base of their individual ids. Which means i have to pass ids of these links to my 4th Activity to display data again in textview.
how to do that. how to fetch ids of these links in textview.
Please let me know if want more info!
Please Help me in this.

Thanks In Advance !

Third Activity Activity3.java

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity{


String passedVar = null;
private TextView passedView = null;

private BooklistHelper dbBookHelper = null;
private Cursor ourCursor = null;
private BookAdapter1 adapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act3);

    passedVar = getIntent().getStringExtra(Activity2.ID_EXTRA1);
    passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passed);

    //ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    dbBookHelper = new BooklistHelper(this);
    ourCursor = dbBookHelper.getBooksByAuthor1(passedVar);
    startManagingCursor(ourCursor);
    adapter = new BookAdapter1(ourCursor);
    //myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(ourCursor != null){
        if(ourCursor.moveToFirst()){
            String value = ourCursor.getString(ourCursor.getColumnIndex("section_content"));
            passedView.setText(Html.fromHtml(""+ value));
        }
    }
    passedView.setLinksClickable(true);

    passedView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
    passedView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

}



class BookAdapter1 extends CursorAdapter{
    BookAdapter1(Cursor c) {
        super(Activity3.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c){
        BookHolder1 holder = (BookHolder1)row.getTag();

        holder.populateFrom(c, dbBookHelper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row3, parent, false);
        BookHolder1 holder = new BookHolder1(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }
}

static class BookHolder1{
    private TextView name = null;
     BookHolder1(View row) {
        name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.bookText1);
    }
     void populateFrom(Cursor c,BooklistHelper r){

         name.setText(r.getName(c));

     }
}
}
```

From this file i get the data in textview from database. now this content have links init. i want to open an activity to display data of these individual links. for this i have get their ids and also tell me what path to be given to these links in databse so that onclick activity can be otained on based of their ids. for this links data i have different table in database.

Comment: Please post related code

Comment: Please check now ...:) , tell me how to make 4th activity file to display data of links present in text.

Comment: Can you post your screens, so that i can understand what you really expecting..

Comment: Is it possible to add one more column in data base to store class path which associated respective data of individual row ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to store the ID's of the link in a `Map` along with the link `String`. That way when you want to get the ID for the link inside a specific text view you just search for the `String` key and then you'll get your ID.

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String,Long>();
map.put("http://www.stackoverflow.com",4);

Long desiredID = map.get(textView.getText());
launchActivity(desiredID);
```

May not be the best way but it is a possibility.

Comment: my data is coming from database and in that the links are present. what path shall i write to link them?

Comment: What do you mean what paths? When you get your links from the database return the ID of the link as well

Comment: ya...but how to get the links from database..?

Comment: Follow this tutorial (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) for information on how to access an SQLite database on your Android device.

Comment: i know how to access database , the textcontent in my database has links for example "this is new, just <a href="">click</a> to see", but i dont want to open this in browser , want to open this in application only so what path that is what link shall is save in mydatabase to access particular link..

Answer (score 0):

try setting value of ID in your textview's tag as

```
String id = "1";
tv.setTag(id);
```

for retrieving you can do as

```
String ret_id = tv.getTag().toString();
```